# RemoteApp and other Windows Server Roles it needs to work

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp

If I'm not enabling my RemoteApps with Web Access, will they still work if I uninstall the Web Server role?

**EDIT**: I've removed the Web Server role and my RemoteApp appears to be working fine. RD Session Host is the only role I have installed. My question now is whether this setup (without RD Web Access/Web Server Roles & RD Gateway) is secure. My RemoteApp appears to be using the RD Session Host's default certificate (not having one of it's own assigned to it during the creation of the RemoteApp).

**NOTE:** From the response so far, I gather not using Web Access with RemoteApp may be an obscure configuration. However, we are just a small business with the need to connect to a SINGLE (custom) application hosted at our central location. I am not sure I really understand the real benefits behind RD Web Access, perhaps because our requirements aren't complicated enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the RDWebAccess (RDWA) role requires the web server role (in particular IIS). The RDWA role provides the functionality of generating the feed that the clients use for app discovery and the necessary RDP files.

Granted that the client machine already has the feed and the RDP files, the RemoteApp side of things will still work and, assuming you have the RDP files, the MSTSC connection will go to the gateway (RDCB) and then to the RDSH/RDVH role.

Comment: So, your answer is: yes, RemoteApps work without the Web Server Role installed (since my question is about using RemoteApps without Web Access)?

Comment: If you have the RDP files, then yes, it will work. You just have to make sure that you have them and that you can still get them if you make any updates to your components. I don't think this scenario has been tested, as it is a bit wacky, plus the user experience is bad, so your mileage might vary.

Comment: Which components are you referring to? If I change the default connection port for Remote Desktop from 3389, for example, I would need to recreate a new .rdp file or .msi installation package and do a re-install of it on all our remote computers?

Comment: Yes, in that case (or e.g.: publish a new app) you would need to find a way to 1) get the RDP file (or simply compose it yourself) and 2) deploy it to all the clients that want to connect.

Comment: Also curious about what you mean by user experience might be bad with this config. The user experience of simply clicking a desktop icon that someone else (myself) is responsible for maintaining, where the app seems to run natively on the desktop -- in contrast to logging into the full desktop, launching the application there and switching back and forth between the remote and local desktops -- seems pretty simple and good.

Comment: But that is the whole purpose of RemoteApp + RDWeb: have a nice user experience. The user navigates to a website, clicks on an icon, the app launches and it looks like it is running locally.

Comment: Users get the same experience (app appears to run locally) without Web Access if an .msi package is installed leaving a desktop icon to click on instead of opening a browser. Where exactly is the benefit of adding Web Access? I gather, when deploying a lot of apps it is easier to organize in the browser with Web Access ... plus it sounds like updates are centrally manageable?

Comment: Yes, Web Access provides a user-friendly central place to access the apps without management hurdles on the administrator (you just push a button, a new app is published, it automatically appears on the website and users can access it immediately). Added value to the administrator is that all setups are the same - in your case, the user can move the file somewhere else, have a different folder structure etc. By restricting what the user can do, the administrator's life is easier :)

Comment: At this point we only have 3 remote computers and 1 app, so I feel it's more of a burden to learn about/install/maintain all the various roles that are available. My setup seems to be working fine with just RDSH. I gather from your answer it should be adopting the connection and security settings of my RDSH configuration?

Comment: OK, fair point :) In terms of maintenance, there should be none on the administrator side (once the setup is done - but you are correct, that can be complicated). I am not sure I understand the last part of your statement - what is "it" referring to?

Comment: Sorry. "it" being my RemoteApp

Comment: Oh, yes. The RDWA role is just a way for the users to get the RDP files in a managed, supervised way. All the settings for the actual connection come from the RDP file, so your connections will go through the same way, regardless of where you get the RDP file. If this helped, make sure to mark my answer as solution :)